TYPO3 extension:setup fails after updated composer.json
I currently run into problems when I want to update my TYPO3 from v11 to v12. My colleague updated the composer.json and is running TYPO3 successfully locally on his system with ddev. We followed the update guides from the official TYPO3 guide
I pulled updated the composer.json which looks like this:
{
    "name": "project/vonvorne",
    "description" : "TYPO3 project",
    "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "typo3/class-alias-loader": true,
            "typo3/cms-composer-installers": true
        },
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.1.8"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./local_packages/*"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "b13/container": "^3.0",
        "causal/ig_ldap_sso_auth": "^4.0",
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^8.1",
        "ichhabrecht/content-defender": "^3.4",
        "ichhabrecht/social-gdpr": "^3.3",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-composer-installers": "^5.0",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-dashboard": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-install": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-linkvalidator": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-opendocs": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-recycler": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-scheduler": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^12.4",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^12.4",
        "typo3/minimal": "^12"
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3 install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3 extension:setup"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
}


when now run ddev composer install I get the followings results in the terminal:
user@w3m18 wrangell-main % ddev composer update
Network ddev-vonvorne_default created 
Building project images... 
Project images built in 0s. 
 Container ddev-vonvorne-db  Created 
 Container ddev-vonvorne-web  Created 
 Container ddev-vonvorne-db  Started 
 Container ddev-vonvorne-web  Started 
Starting Mutagen sync process... 
Mutagen sync flush completed in 1s.
For details on sync status 'ddev mutagen st vonvorne -l' 
Waiting for web/db containers to become ready: [web db] 
Starting ddev-router if necessary... 
 Container ddev-router  Running 
Waiting for additional project containers to become ready... 
All project containers are now ready. 
TYPO3 does not seem to have been set up yet, missing settings.php (/Users/user/Code/zip/vonvorne/wrangell-main/config/system/settings.php) 
Generating additional.php file for database connection. 
Composer could not detect the root package (project/vonvorne) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See https://getcomposer.org/root-version
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
Generating class alias map file
Publishing public assets of TYPO3 extensions
Published public assets
  > typo3 install:fixfolderstructure
No action performed!
> typo3 extension:setup

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Too few arguments to function TYPO3\CMS\Core\ExpressionLanguage\ProviderConfigurationLoader::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 2985 and exactly 3 expected
thrown in file /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/ExpressionLanguage/ProviderConfigurationLoader.php
in line 29

Script typo3 extension:setup handling the typo3-cms-scripts event returned with error code 1
Script @typo3-cms-scripts was called via post-autoload-dump
Task failed: Exec command 'composer install' in container/service 'web': exit status 1 
A task failure does not mean that DDEV failed, but your hook configuration has a command that failed. 
Composer could not detect the root package (project/vonvorne) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See https://getcomposer.org/root-version
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 58 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading b13/container (3.0.0 => 3.1.1)
  - Upgrading bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.8 => v3.0.1)
  - Upgrading causal/ig_ldap_sso_auth (4.0.1 => 4.0.2)
  - Upgrading doctrine/deprecations (1.1.3 => 1.1.4)
  - Upgrading enshrined/svg-sanitize (0.18.0 => 0.20.0)
  - Upgrading firebase/php-jwt (v6.10.1 => v6.10.2)
  - Upgrading ichhabrecht/content-defender (3.4.3 => 3.5.1)
  - Upgrading phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.5.1 => 5.6.1)
  - Upgrading phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.9.0 => 1.10.0)
  - Upgrading symfony/cache (v6.4.14 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/cache-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1)
  - Upgrading symfony/console (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15)
  - Upgrading symfony/dependency-injection (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1)
  - Upgrading symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v6.4.14 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/messenger (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/options-resolver (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/process (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15)
  - Upgrading symfony/property-info (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/rate-limiter (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15)
  - Upgrading symfony/routing (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16)
  - Upgrading symfony/service-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1)
  - Upgrading symfony/string (v6.4.13 => v6.4.15)
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-adminpanel (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-backend (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-belog (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-beuser (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-cli (3.1.1 => 3.1.2)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-core (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-dashboard (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-extbase (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-extensionmanager (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-felogin (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-filelist (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-filemetadata (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-fluid (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-form (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-frontend (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-impexp (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-info (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-install (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-linkvalidator (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-lowlevel (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-opendocs (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-recycler (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-redirects (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-reports (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-scheduler (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-seo (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-setup (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-sys-note (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-t3editor (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-tstemplate (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-viewpage (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 58 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-cli (3.1.1 => 3.1.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/routing (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/options-resolver (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/rate-limiter (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/messenger (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/service-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v6.4.14 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/cache-contracts (v3.5.0 => v3.5.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/cache (v6.4.14 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading doctrine/deprecations (1.1.3 => 1.1.4): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/dependency-injection (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/string (v6.4.13 => v6.4.15): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/console (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading firebase/php-jwt (v6.10.1 => v6.10.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading enshrined/svg-sanitize (0.18.0 => 0.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.8 => v3.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-core (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-backend (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading b13/container (3.0.0 => 3.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading causal/ig_ldap_sso_auth (4.0.1 => 4.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/property-info (v6.4.13 => v6.4.16): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.9.0 => 1.10.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.5.1 => 5.6.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-extbase (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-fluid (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-install (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-frontend (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-extensionmanager (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/process (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading ichhabrecht/content-defender (3.4.3 => 3.5.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v6.4.14 => v6.4.15): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-adminpanel (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-belog (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-beuser (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-dashboard (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-felogin (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-filemetadata (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-form (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-impexp (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-info (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-linkvalidator (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-lowlevel (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-opendocs (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-recycler (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-redirects (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-reports (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-scheduler (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-seo (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-setup (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-sys-note (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-t3editor (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-tstemplate (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-viewpage (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading typo3/cms-filelist (v12.4.22 => v12.4.24): Extracting archive
Generating autoload files
Generating class alias map file
Publishing public assets of TYPO3 extensions
Published public assets
  > typo3 install:fixfolderstructure
No action performed!
> typo3 extension:setup

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Too few arguments to function TYPO3\CMS\Core\ExpressionLanguage\ProviderConfigurationLoader::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 2985 and exactly 3 expected
thrown in file /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/ExpressionLanguage/ProviderConfigurationLoader.php
in line 29

Script typo3 extension:setup handling the typo3-cms-scripts event returned with error code 1
Script @typo3-cms-scripts was called via post-autoload-dump
Composer [update] failed, composer command failed: exit status 1. stderr= 
user@w3m18 wrangell-main % 

I flushed the caches via TYPO3 cli, no success.

TYPO3 does not seem to have been set up yet, missing settings.php (/Users/user/Code/zip/vonvorne/wrangell-main/config/system/settings.php) 
Is the mentioned file present?

mentioned file is not present.

Your TYPO3 won't work without that settings.php. It should be generated during the upgrade process. In former TYPO3 versions the settings were stored in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php. So maybe your colleague forgot to add settings.php to your Git repository / your local copy of the project.
